# queue a number of effects synchronously with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-2.0

Is there are more readable way to queue a number of asynchronous effects that they are executed synchronously?

```
var element1 = $('#div1');
var element2 = $('#div2');

$(element2).hide();
$(element1).on('click',function(){   
    $(element1).fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(element2).fadeIn(1000, function(){
            $(element2).hide();
            alert('hello');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't this easily readable?

Comment: not if you want to queue 20 effects in a row.

Comment: @Zim84 Thats the reason behind my question.

Comment: As a complete aside: `element1` and `element2` in your example are already jQuery objects so no need to wrap them again in `$()`.

Comment: @Elisa, would be this and idea? http://jsfiddle.net/wa85V/

Comment: @John - Id say make an answer out of the code that is in that fiddle. Seems like a perfectly good suggestion to me.

Comment: @Jamiec, I added my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16635124/1420197). :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the ever-deeper nesting effect if you use a promise-based system.

```
$.when(
    $(element1).fadeOut(1000)
).then(function () {
    return $(element2).fadeIn(1000);
}).then(function () {
    return $(element2).hide();
}).then(function () {
    return $(element1).fadeIn(1000);
}).then(function () {
    return $(element1).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tYhNq/1

You'll notice this makes it very easy to change the order of the animations.

The "trick" is that the [`$.when()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) returns the promise object associated with the first animation, so then you can just chain a bunch of [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) calls, noting that each `then()` callback should return the result of its animation.

Of course you can directly chain animations on the same element, e.g. `.fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100)...`

Comment: I would prefer a $.when at the start and remove the .promise like:  $.when($(element1).fadeOut(1000)) and so on... thats more clear I think.

Comment: You're right. `$.when()` is neater as seen in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYhNq/1/). (`.promise()` was just the first way that came to mind.)

Comment: Can you please modify your solution with the $.when? then I mark it as answer :) just for the others...nobody need to read comments...

Comment: OK, done, with the explanation rephrased a little to (I hope) make sense with the changed code.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called "[**callback hell**](http://callbackhell.com/)". In NodeJS you have [**async**](https://github.com/caolan/async/) module option to "escape" from it.

I didn't find a correspondent option in jQuery.

My suggestion is to create one function for every effect, like bellow:

```
var element1 = $('#div1');
var element2 = $('#div2');

$(element2).hide();

var finished = function () { console.log(":-)"); }
var hide = function () { element2.hide(); finished(); }
var fadeIn = function () { element2.fadeIn(1000, hide); }
var clicked = function () { element1.fadeOut(1000, fadeIn); }

$(element1).on('click', clicked);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wa85V/)